# XMP data written from commons io imaging not readable by metadata-extractor

Tags: java, image-processing, apache-commons, exiftool, metadata-extractor

I am using commons io imaging library to add xmp metadata to a JPEG file. This is how I'm doing it:

```
   String xmpXml = "<dc:decription>some sample desc123</dc:description>";
   JpegXmpRewriter rewriter = new JpegXmpRewriter();
   rewriter.updateXmpXml(is,os, xmpXml);
```

Running `exiftool` on the above file shows the created xmp data from above:

```
$ exiftool 167_sample.jpg | grep "Description"
Description                  : some sample desc123
```

However, using [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) I can't read the `Description` tag from above:

```
Metadata metadata = com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file.inputStream) 
for (XmpDirectory xmpDirectory : metadata.getDirectoriesOfType(XmpDirectory.class)) {
    XMPMeta xmpMeta = xmpDirectory.getXMPMeta();
    XMPIterator itr = xmpMeta.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        XMPPropertyInfo property = (XMPPropertyInfo) itr.next();
        System.out.println(property.getPath() + ": " + property.getValue());
    }
}
```

More interestingly, `metadata-extractor` **CAN** read the `Description` tag when `exiftool` is used to create the xmp tag

```
$ exiftool -xmp-dc:description=Manuallyaddedthis 167_sample.jpg

Metadata metadata = com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new File ("167_sample.jpg")) 
for (XmpDirectory xmpDirectory : metadata.getDirectoriesOfType(XmpDirectory.class)) {
    XMPMeta xmpMeta = xmpDirectory.getXMPMeta();
    XMPIterator itr = xmpMeta.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        XMPPropertyInfo property = (XMPPropertyInfo) itr.next();
        System.out.println(property.getPath() + ": " + property.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, this question follows from issue https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/200

Answer (score 0):

metadata-extractor produces an error for the (second, "self-adhesive labels") image you attached to this issue:

> ERROR: Error processing XMP data: XML parsing failure

Looking further, it seems that the XMP XML contains only the following:

```
<dc:description>some sample description</dc:description>
```

In the first line of the code you posted, it's clear why.

This is not a valid XMP document. Adobe's XMPCore library isn't accepting it.

You might like to use the XMPCore library to produce a valid XMP document. Alternatively, add the relevant parent tag(s).